# Accessibility and the tab key

Tags: html, wai-aria

This question is about accessibility issue I have on one of my websites, when I use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key I get a few errors:

1. Only some parts of the navigation bar are selected
2. I cannot see which part is currently selected
3. Tabs are only going over navigation bar and not continuing to content

How can I address these issues? any good tutorials on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete list for you to search for the problematic area:

[Techniques and Failures for Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0 from W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140311/Overview.html#contents)

Some pages provide code/resources:
[C15: Using CSS to change the presentation of a user interface component when it receives focus](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140311/C15.html)

[G1: Adding a link at the top of each page that goes directly to the main content area (Skip to content)](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G1.html)

Comment: Those are merely specification pages, not implementation examples which is what I lack. Do you know any good tutorials or examples for this online?

Comment: You can also find some tips in [BBC Accessibility site](http://www.bbc.co.uk/guidelines/futuremedia/accessibility/)